# How do I install delayedresult module in wxPython

Tags: multithreading, wxpython

I have installed and used wxPython on my work pc (using threading in many apps). However, I attempted to set-up the same environment on my personal computer, and I cannot get the module lib.delayed result to run for anything. I can use wxPython with my applications that don't use threading, but when I attempt to run any app that uses threading, I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
import lib.delayedresult
ImportError: No module named lib.delayedresult
```

I've exhausted what I know to do, at this point .... I appreciate any help/direction in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am using it by importing like:

```
import wx.lib.delayedresult as delayedresult
```

Comment: I used it that way too, to no avail .... I'm in the process of re-istalling everything

Comment: I see.  I never had an issue with 2.8 series. How about installing 2.8 and use wxversion to switch back?